# the component for route 'Detail' must be a React component

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working in a `react native` project running simulator on my device using "expo"
I have got an error and tried to solve may times but failed
here is link of my error

[image]

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import MovieList from './components/list';
import  Detail from './components/detail';


import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  MovieList: {screen: MovieList},
  Detail: {screen: Detail},

})

const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default App();
```

**detail.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function Detail() {

  return (
    <View>
   <Text>Details</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  item: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#282C35'
  },
  itemText: {
color: '#fff',
fontSize: 24
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is here

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  MovieList: {screen: MovieList},
  Detail: {screen: **Detail**},

})
```

Because of you declare the **Detail** a function. And **StackNavigator** needs the **Component**

For e.g.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class Detail extends Component {
// Your Code

}
```

This how its working fine Use component instead the function.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you need to replace**

`import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';`

**with**

`import createAppContainer from 'react-navigation';
import createStackNavigator from 'react-navigation-stack';`

Because you used export default in the `createAppContainer` / `createStackNavigator`  component's source file, you don't need the destructuring on the `import`.

Comment: it uses the third library, so the import is correct. you can see the source code or official api